# How do I save a captured image into my phone gallery in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to take a picture using camera intent and save it to the gallery. How can I do that. I tried from:
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto 
But, haven't been able to do it. So, what could be the solution to take a picture and save it to the gallery when the button is clicked. I have been able to save it in the devide_picture/device/dcim.

Comment: `to take a picture using camera intent`. Then the Camera app will already store that image in the DCIM folder. You do not have to save it yet again. The Camera app will also inform the Media Store about the new image. Upon which Gallery apps will show it. I wonder what you do for strange things that you save an image yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I save a captured image into my phone gallery in android?

You don't. You save a captured image as a file. A gallery app can then display that file.

> I have been able to save it in the devide_picture/device/dcim.

Then you are almost done. You need to tell `MediaStore` that your new file exists, as the camera app might not do that:

```
MediaScannerConnection
        .scanFile(ctxt,
          new String[] {f.getAbsolutePath()},
          new String[] {"image/jpeg"}, null);
```

(where `ctxt` is a `Context`, such as your `Activity`, and `f` is a `File` object pointing to where you saved the photo)

Comment: 606k ?? Where do yet four thousand points come from in a week? I'm baffled!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's done and you saved a lot of effort. thanks a lot